# I'm trying to get started in python, and I want to make an image appear on screen

Tags: python

I want to learn python, but I don't really know where to start. I don't want to fall into a tutorial hellhole, so I'm trying to make an image just pop up on screen. For some reason it won't work.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init
pygame.sprite(playerv3, bgd=None)
```

Comment: Stack overflow isn't quite the right place for this
But I started my python journey with [codeacademy.com](https://www.codecademy.com/)

Comment: There's books, tutorials, and most importantly: search engines. Then start writing some code.

Comment: I suggest giving yourself a problem that you would use python to solve.  Something like create a website that displays the time.  Or a command line utility that looks up the price of a stock.  That way you get your hands dirty right away.    I do recommend the Django tutorial.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Request for external resources are off-topic, and questions like this tend to get too many opinion based answers.. You may want to read [ask].

Comment: CodeAcademy is for learning the basics. You need to continue on this path by setting yourself projects that get more complex and bigger over time. Later, you should use libraries to avoid reinventing the wheel for everything and to get things done. [Here](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python) you can see a huge list of libraries that can prove to be very useful. My experience has been that you only really learn something if you need it as a solution for your own project. This means that a hell lot of research is required at the beginning.

Comment: Please do not completely edit your question to make existing comments and answers no longer applicable. As it stands the edited question would have been closed for lack of debugging details anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was in almost this spot 2 years ago, when I wanted to learn to make games. Here I am now, with experience in multiple languages. Best place to start, by far, is YouTube or some other place that has tutorials. There are lots that can help you. A simple search for 'Beginner Python Tutorials' goes a long way. I wish you luck in such journeys.

Comment: This is definitely better suited to a comment than an answer.